# Is Mogre (essentially Ogre, but C#) dead? If so what would be a viable alternative to it?

Tags: unity, ogre, mogre

I've been looking around for a 3D engine where I can use C# to replace Unity lately, but haven't really come up with much. Ogre looked promising, but it wasn't C# however Mogre is. Sadly looks like it hasn't been updated since Feb. 2014.

With the said are there any viable alternatives to it, or Unity? Or better yet is there a nightly I missed somewhere for Mogre?